# Does "applemaps-x-callback://" exist?

Tags: google-maps, apple-maps

Google Maps provides a convenient URL scheme:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://
```

for using when firing Google Maps from an iOS app.
Does Apple Maps provide the same kind of feature.
If yes I would like to find some short sample code, in order to know how to use it.
I did some research, but didn't notice any thing similar.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked for the same functionality in Apple Maps. It doesn't seem possible. Apple's documentation of the maps URL scheme does not show anything like this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html